# How can I create nodes and create a one-to-many relationship another newly created node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
    UNWIND $likedMovies AS likedMovie
    MERGE (lm:LikedMovie {
      id: likedMovie.id,
      name: likedMovie.name,
    })

    CREATE p = (:Person $person)-[:LIKES]->(lm)
```

This doesn't solve my problem as it creates a new Person for every `likedMovie`
Instead I want the single `Person` to be related to all the `likedMovie`'s

I also tried this:

```
    UNWIND $likedMovies AS likedMovie
    MERGE (lm:LikedMovie {
      id: likedMovie.id,
      name: likedMovie.name,
    })

    CREATE p = (:Person $person)

    FOREACH (lm in likedMovie | 
       MERGE (p)->[:LIKES]-(lm)
    )
```

But, it's giving me an error that `p` is a Path and needs to be a `Node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assigned p = (:Person), it created a path with nodes in it. But if you assign a variable (p:Person), the variable p is the node itself. Thus, you can use it to create your relationship with p one-to-many.

```
CREATE (p:Person $person)
UNWIND $likedMovies AS likedMovie
WITH p, likedMovie
MERGE (p)-[:LIKES]->(likedMovie)
```

Answer (score 0):

This template should do it (although I do not know what is in `$person` )

```
  CREATE (p:Person {name: $person})

  FOREACH(m in $likedMovies |
      MERGE (lm:LikedMovie {id: m.id, name: m.name})
      MERGE (p)-[:LIKES]->(lm)
  )
```